# Hide element based on boolean variable in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I have angularJS for frontend, and ruby on rails for backend. I am searching for a permission in the backend, and if it is false, I want to hide the element in the frontend.

In html.erb file

```
<% if @has_permission %>
<div>Content</div>
<%end%>
```

In ruby controller,

```
before_action :check_permission
def check_permission
  @has_permission=false
end
```

Just this logic doesn't hide the div. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Should work if it's the same controller. Try putting debugger in `check_permission` to check if it's getting executed

Comment: Yes, it is getting executed. I logged something in the function too, just to be sure.

Comment: From the information you have provided, I would not expect the `<div>Content</div>` to display. There must be some other important information missing, such as some other code in the controller that sets `@has_permission` to a truthy value. Or, perhaps the `html.erb` file is not getting rendered at all; perhaps you're rendering a different file.

Comment: Add here log, in it we can see from where and how it renders